# Create CloudFront service (to have https in my site) with github actions or with backend code?

Tags: github-actions, backend, amazon-cloudfront, serverless, serverless-framework

I have a frontend code that is deployed through github actions in every push to an S3 bucket. On the other hand, I want to have https in my static website so I also want to create a CloudFront distribution service. My question is: should I create the service together with the actions in the frontend or is it OK to deploy it separately with my backend code using my .yml template file? thanks!

Comment: You can deploy your infra separately, and configure your pipeline to update the content in S3 every time it is run.

Comment: Just personal preference, really. What you want to do will probably depend on details of your project and how you (and your team(s)?) work on it. Sometimes, projects will have separate teams for frontend and backend and you want the ability to deploy frontend and backend changes independently. Other times, you may choose to deploy them together for simplicity, like if a sole developer or single team maintains both the frontend and backend and they often release dependent changes together.